# Does Pregel allow the structure of a graph to be modified?

Tags: graph

If it does, how can it archive good performance when the graph needs modifying?
What I mean by modifying is to add or remove  vertices or edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, pregel allows the structure to be modified. This is called mutations. It is presented in the section 3.4 Topology Mutations of the paper.

According to the paper, available at (http://kowshik.github.io/JPregel/pregel_paper.pdf):

> "Multiple vertices may issue conflicting requests in the same
>   superstep (e.g., two requests to add a vertex V , with different
>   initial values). We use two mechanisms to achieve determinism: partial
>   ordering and handlers.
>
> As with messages, mutations become effective in the superstep after
>   the requests were issued. Within that superstep removals are performed
>   first, with edge removal before vertex removal, since removing a
>   vertex implicitly removes all of its out-edges. Additions follow
>   removals, with vertex addition before edge addition, and all mutations
>   precede calls to Compute(). This partial ordering yields deterministic
>   results for most con icts.
>
> The remaining conflicts are resolved by user-defined handlers. If
>   there are multiple requests to create the same vertex in the same
>   superstep, then by default the system just picks one arbitrarily, but
>   users with special needs may specify a better conflict resolution
>   policy by defining an appropriate handler method in their Vertex
>   subclass. The same handler mechanism is used to resolve conflicts
>   caused by multiple vertex removal requests, or by multiple edge
>   addition or removal requests. We delegate the resolution to handlers
>   to keep the code of Compute() simple, which limits the interaction
>   between a handler and Compute(), but has not been an issue in
>   practice."